# Computing the cohomology ring of $T = S^1 \times S^1$ using simplicial cohomology definitions

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am attempting to compute the cohomology ring of $T$ with the cup product using simplicial cohomology (with notation coming from the following image) and I am not seeing that all of my generators square to zero. [image: Torus]

I was able to compute that $H^0_{\Delta}(T)= \mathbf{Z}$, $H^1_{\Delta}(T) =\mathbf{Z}^2$, $H^2_{\Delta}(T)= \mathbf{Z}$ by noting that the chain complex $\Delta_0(T)= \langle v\rangle$

$\Delta_1(T)= \langle a, b, c \rangle$

$\Delta_2(T)= \langle U, L \rangle$.

So applying $Hom(-, \mathbf{Z})$ to each group in the complex yields:

$Hom(\Delta_0(T), \mathbf{Z}) = \langle v^* \rangle$ ($v^*(v) = 1$ and is zero else),

$Hom(\Delta_1(T), \mathbf{Z}) = \langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rangle$ ($\alpha = a^*, \beta = b^*, \gamma = c^*$)

$Hom(\Delta_2(T), \mathbf{Z}) = \langle \mu, \eta \rangle$, $\mu = U^*, \eta = L^*$)

Now given that the coboundary map $\delta = \partial^*$ and so

$\delta(v^*) = v^*(\partial) = 0$ since $\partial : \{a, b, c\} \to \{0\}$ giving us the zeroth cohomology being generated by the class $[v^*]$.

$\delta(\alpha) = \delta( \beta) = -\delta(\gamma) = \mu + \eta$ and so our space has basis $\langle \alpha +\gamma, \alpha - \beta, \alpha \rangle$ with kernel being generated by $\langle \alpha + \gamma, \alpha - \beta \rangle$. Since $Im(\delta_0) = \{0\}$, we have that first cohomology is generated by the classes $$\langle [\alpha + \gamma], [\alpha - \beta] \rangle$$

Lastly, we have that $ker(\delta_2) = \langle \mu + \eta, \eta \rangle$ and $Im(\delta_1) = \langle \mu + \eta \rangle$ making the second cohomology generated by $\langle [\eta] \rangle$.

Now to compute the ring structure with the cup product I use the following definition from Hatcher:

For $\phi \in H^k(X; R)$, $\psi \in H^l(X; R)$, we define for $\sigma \in \Delta_{k+l}(X)$ $(\phi \cup \psi)(\sigma) = \phi(\sigma_{[v_0, ..., v_k]}) \cdot \psi(\sigma_{v_k, ..., v_{k+l}})$

Now the chains we have to evaluate our cohomology on are $\sigma_v$, $\sigma_a, \sigma_b, \sigma_c$, and $\sigma_U, \sigma_L$ (where the subscript indicates its image in $T$). Using the above definition we see that $[v^*] \cup [v^*](\sigma_v) = [v^*](\sigma_v)[v^*](\sigma_v) = (1)(1) = 1$ and so this is the unit of the ring.

Where I am having some confusion is using the cup product definition, I am not getting that $[\alpha - \beta] \cup [\alpha - \beta] = 0$, instead from my calculations I get that if we label the vertices $v_0, v_1, v_2$ in an orientation preserving order on the image above, then evaluating the cup product of $[\alpha - \beta]$ with itself on $\sigma_{U} = \sigma_{[v_0, v_1, v_2]}$ yields $[\alpha - \beta] \cup [\alpha - \beta](\sigma_{[v_0, v_1, v_2]}) = [\alpha - \beta](\sigma_{[v_0, v_1]})[\alpha - \beta](\sigma_{[v_1, v_2]}) = [\alpha - \beta](\sigma_a)[\alpha - \beta](\sigma_b) = (1)(-1) =-1 \neq 0$.

Where am I going wrong in this calculation?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The oversight here is that the cocycle $[\alpha-\beta] \cup [\alpha-\beta]$ does not evaluate to $0$ everywhere. However, it is a coboundary, and will therefore be $0$.

To see that $[\alpha-\beta] \cup [\alpha-\beta]$ is a coboundary, we see that
$$
[\alpha-\beta] \cup [\alpha-\beta](U)=(\alpha-\beta)(a)(\alpha-\beta)(b)=-1, \\
[\alpha-\beta] \cup [\alpha-\beta](L)=(\alpha-\beta)(b)(\alpha-\beta)(a)=-1.
$$
Thus $[\alpha-\beta] \cup [\alpha-\beta]=-(U^*+L^*)=-(\mu+\eta)$. Since the image of $\delta^1$ is generated by $\mu+\eta$, we get that it is indeed a coboundary.